# jquery resizeing child div not refreshing content of div above it

Tags: jquery

Resizing first div not refreshing content of first div drawing content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#first').layout({
        applyDefaultStyles: false
    });

    $('#second').layout({
        applyDefaultStyles: false
    });
</script>

<div id="assembly" class="clearfix">
    <div id="breadcrumbs" class="ui-layout-north">
        <div class="inner">
            @{Html.RenderPartial(T4MVC.SharedController.ViewNames._ProductCatalogBrandCrambs, Model);}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-layout-center" id="first">
        <div id="drawing" class="ui-layout-north" style="overflow:hidden;" >
            @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/ProductCatalog/DrawingViewerPartial.cshtml", Model);}
        </div>
        <div id="description" class="ui-layout-center">
            <div style="HEIGHT: 23px; WIDTH: 100%; border: 1px; padding: 0; background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);" class="gridHeader">
                  Description
            </div>
            <div>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/ProductCatalog/PartialPartDesc.cshtml", Model);}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-layout-east" id="second">
        <div id="bom-list" class="ui-layout-north">
            @{Html.RenderPartial(SOTWebMVC.Controllers.ProductCatalogController.ViewNames._BOMPartial, Model);}
        </div>
        <div id="spec" class="ui-layout-center">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/ProductCatalog/PartialPartSpec.cshtml", Model);}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give more information. What is the desired behaviour, and what is not working. Also only post the necessary, and the RENDERED HTML. We cannot start guessing what you need. Be as elaborate and clear as possible.

Comment: there are two divs within "first" div "drawing" and "description" , resizer is displaying between div "drawing" and "description" , when i resize using resizer, content of drawing is hiding, I am new in Jquery